# Integrate Firebase with Android

Tags: android, firebase

I followed the required steps to integrate Firebase in my Android project but unfortunately I have the error : Unknown host 'jcenter.bintray.com'. You may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle.

This is happening when I adding :
[EDIT] with the content of the file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
    jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

to my build.gradle file. Without this line, I can sync the project without issue.

Proxy settings (at work):

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=3.187.156.241
systemProp.http.proxyPort=88
```

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Can u show the rest of the gradle file, and tell us what your proxy settings are

Comment: Post full `Gradle` so that we can suggest and also tell what proxy settings you have what @TimCastelijns Sir said.

Comment: Gradle file looks OK. It's probably the proxy